# Find the employees who have NO dependents using EXCEPT (MINUS)

Tags: sql, mysql, except

I'm practicing using MySQL lately and when I studied the EXCEPT (MINUS) operator in MySQL, I encoutered some problem:
I have two tables 'employees' and 'dependents'.
Tables "employees":

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (
    employee_id INT (11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR (20) DEFAULT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    phone_number VARCHAR (20) DEFAULT NULL,
    hire_date DATE NOT NULL,
    job_id INT (11) NOT NULL,
    salary DECIMAL (8, 2) NOT NULL,
    manager_id INT (11) DEFAULT NULL,
    department_id INT (11) DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (job_id) REFERENCES jobs (job_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (department_id) REFERENCES departments (department_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES employees (employee_id));
```

+Table "dependents":

```sql
CREATE TABLE dependents (
    dependent_id INT (11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    relationship VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    employee_id INT (11) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employees (employee_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

I tried to find the info of employees with no dependents, using the below query:

```sql
SELECT e.employee_id, CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name) Employee
FROM employees e
WHERE e.employee_id IN (
    SELECT  e.employee_id  
    FROM employees e
    EXCEPT  
    SELECT  d.employee_id
    FROM dependents d
    ORDER BY employee_id);
```

The query ran successfully, though, I notice it different from what I expected. When I ran the subquery seperately, I got result of only 12 employees (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeP9d.png), though, the query above gave out the result of 22 employees (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yk6Q.png)]. I also noticed there were some with dependents, which did not meet my requirement.
Can someone help me fix the above query, thank you!
P/s: I expected my final results to look like this:
[The expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcbfR.png)

=> With total of 12 employees , which the employee_id follow the figure (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeP9d.png)

Comment: *I studied the EXCEPT (MINUS) function in MySQL* EXCEPT is an operator, not a function.

Comment: Provide a sample according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL` check to achieve what you are looking for :

```
SELECT e.employee_id, CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name) AS Employee
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN dependents d ON e.employee_id = d.employee_id
WHERE d.employee_id IS NULL
ORDER BY e.employee_id;
```

Comment: I mean, yes, I tried it already. But I wanted to solve the question in many ways, therefore, I tried to find the employees using EXCEPT. Though, thanks for your answer!